# Setting error-page in zk.xml causes exception in JBoss

Tags: jboss, zk

I set up error-page in zk.xml, but it throws IllegalStateException in Jboss: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot reset buffer after response has been committed

However, it works fine in Tomcat. Is it a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the workaround for this issue, you can remove the **javax.servlet.error.exception** in the error.zul page.
For example,

```
<zscript>
    execution.removeAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
</zscript>
```

Or use the latest ZK version, which has fixed [the bug](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1144)